# [Processing 2.0]Trying to create an array of random integers and then bubble sort them

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, processing, bubble-sort

Im trying to come up with an array of random integers in processing and then use bubble sort to sort them, but I want to print the list of random integers unsorted first and then sort and print, also I wanted the array to be between (1-100). This is the code I wrote attempting this but I think i might be way off. Thanks for any replies.

```
int[] arr = new int[10];


int min  = 1;
int max = 100;
int Random = int(random(min, max));
int R0 = int(random(min, max));
int R1 = int(random(min, max)); 
int R2 = int(random(min, max));
int R3 = int(random(min, max));
int R4 = int(random(min, max));
int R5 = int(random(min, max));
int R6 = int(random(min, max));
int R7 = int(random(min, max));
int R8 = int(random(min, max));
int R9 = int(random(min, max));



println ("The Length of the Array is: " + arr.length);
println ("The " + arr.length + " random numbers chosen between (" + min + " - " + max   + ") are: " + R0 + ", " + R1 + ", " + R2 + ", " + R3 + ", " + R4 + ", " + R5+ ", " + R6 + ", " + R7 + ", " + R8 + ", " + R9 + ".");
for (int i = 0; i <100;  i++)
 {  print((arr[i]= Random + i ) + ", ");

}
```

EDIT: The final revised version I came up with:

```
int Random = int(random(10, 100));

int[] array = new int[Random]; // RANDOM SIZE OF ARRAY
int min  = 10; // MINIMUM RANDOM INTEGER CHOSEN
int max = 100; // MAX RANDOM INTEGER CHOSEN

int temp;


for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = (int)random(min,max);
}
println("The Amount of Numbers That Will Be Chosen Is: " + array.length);
println("The Unsorted Numbers Chosen Are Between (" + min + " - " + max + ").");
println();
println("The Numbers Are:");
println(array);
println();
println("The Sorting Begins");


  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)   
{
  println();
  println("Step " + i);  // Prints the step of insertion using "i" as the counter

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
  {
      print(array[j] + ", ");
      if (array[i] < array[j])
    {
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
        }
      }
      println();
   }
```

Comment: http://www.helpwithprogramming.com/do-my-java-homework/

Comment: "think i might be way off". How would you assess that? What result do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why are you creating individual values for your randoms.  You should be doing something like this:

```
int[] iArr = new int[50];
for (int i=0; i<iArr.length; i++) {
  iArr[i] = (int)random(min,max);
}
```

That will create an array of 50 and fill it with random numbers, using your code above.

Next you need to print unsorted:

```
System.out.println("Unsorted:");
for(int i=0; i<iArr.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(iArr[i]);
}
```

Then you do your bubble sort, then call the above again to print them in order.

Answer (score 0):

> also I wanted the array to be between (1-100)

Hint: use `Random` class which provides a nice function `nextInt(int n)` function: Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between `0` (*inclusive*) and the specified value `n` (*exclusive*), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.